# How can I use try/catch in TypeORM without throwing an error myself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, try-catch, typeorm

I want to use async/await with try/catch and TypeORM. When there is no User found it returns undefined so it doesn't enter the catch block.

```
let user;
  try {
    user = await findOneById(id);
    if (!user) throw Error();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
return user;
```

Is there a way to enter the catch block without throwing an error?
If so how?

Comment: Are you saying that if there is no user found then it is an error? Because usually an error is if you don't pass correct params or there is no db connection. If there is no user found, you probably don't want to throw an error.

Comment: No need to use try catch here. Just use a conditional to check value of user and if null or undefined then do what you do inside this catch block.

Comment: @Stretch0 no, when there is no user returned it is simply undefined and doesnt enter the catch block. But I expected it to work with async/await.

Comment: @FrixG Ok, am doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem solved? Also, can you provide the complete enclosing function for better analysis?

Comment: @Behrooz Yes it is solved. The try/catch works but was unnecessary in this case. Thank you for your time anyway.